# Can I license my project with an open-source license but disallow commercial use?

Tags: licensing, license-recommendation, commercial

I'd like to make my project open-source. Is there a free/open-source license that lets me do that, but disallows anyone receiving my project to use it for commercial purposes or monetary gain?

In a similar vein, what if I find a project that says it's open-source but its license disallows using it for commercial purposes or monetary gain?

---

<sub>This is a [canonical question](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/q/855/98). New questions asking effectively the same thing as either of the above questions may be closed as a duplicate of this one.</sub>

Comment: Anyone aspiring to write an answer should bear in mind that the [terms of reference](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of the site say that we use the FSF's definition of *free* and the OSI's definition of *open source*.

Comment: It might also be pertinent to mention that answers on this site are [prohibited from recommending "source available" licenses](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/q/849/30377), including any non-commercial terms. Such licenses exist, but recommendations will need to be found elsewhere.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

## No free/open-source license may disallow commercial use.

The whole purpose of the Free and Open movements is an altruistic one: if you're making your project free and open, you're gifting it to the public at large, under certain terms (which often boil down to "attribute it back to me"). See the [Open Source Definition](https://opensource.org/osd-annotated) for some explanation of what these movements are trying to achieve, and why no open-source license can disallow commercial use.

One of the central tenets of these movements is that they do not discriminate: your software becomes something that *anyone* can use, no matter for what purpose they're using it. Point 6 of the Definition sums it up: "No Discrimination Against Fields of Endeavor". You can't say "open-source but non-commercial", because that does exactly that - discriminates against those who wish to use your software for commercial purposes.

## What? But it's *mine*! Surely I can restrict it!

Sure, you can, if you *really* want to. What you can't do is restrict commercial use and still call your project open-source. As the copyright holder, it's your prerogative to restrict any kind of use of your software, if you wish to, or to keep it to yourself and not allow anyone else to use it at all. If that's what you want to do, that's your right - but the Open Source movement is about sharing gratuitously, not about excessive restriction; you can place restrictions on your own software, but you can't truthfully claim that it's still truly open-source.

## But I found X project that restricts commercial use and *they* call it open-source!

They're lying to you - though whether that's intentional or not, who knows. Sorry. See above. Refer the maintainers of that project here, if you're not sure whether or not they know the difference.

A number of people use "open source" to mean ["source-available"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-available_software), thinking the two are synonymous. For many purposes, they are, but a strict interpretation of the term "open source", as coined by the open-source movement, includes the philosophy of not placing restrictions on the use of the licensed software.

## So what *can* I do?

You can **dual-license** your software. This is a very common model: you offer your software, open-source, under the terms of a [copyleft](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/42/98) license. Anyone can use this, for any purpose, but since a copyleft license requires that the project developed around your software be distributed under the same (or similar) license, using a copyleft-licensed project for commercial purposes is often more difficult than with a permissive license.

At the same time, you advertise that you also offer your project under a closed-source license that offers the licensee more freedom (and the ability to not have to redistribute their software as open-source too). The catch? You *sell* these licenses, rather than giving them away. If someone wants to pay you to be able to use your software for commercial purposes, you sell them one of these licenses, and you both win.

If you just want to disallow any commercial activity using your software, no matter whether they're paying or not, you have two options:

1. Use a license that disallows commercial activity, and accept that you can't truthfully call your project open-source or free software.
2. Use a copyleft license (such as the GNU GPL) and accept that although it'll be more difficult to use your software for commercial purposes, it may still happen.

Comment: I would recommend that anyone with anything to add write their own answer, and allow the community to express themselves through voting.  There is no reason why a canonical **question** should have only one canonical **answer**, though I would hope that, over time - through critical commentary, edits, and voting - one emerges as *primus inter pares*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108212/discussion-on-answer-by-artofcode-can-i-license-my-project-with-an-open-source-l).  (If that link doesn't work for you, it may well be because you don't have enough [reputation](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to chat here.)

Comment: I wish I could have you summarize these points for our Legal Dept. The hoops we jump through with non-experts is crazy.

Comment: @J.Hirsch Link 'em here :)

Comment: I've just purged a whole bunch more comments from this answer.  Please do not post comments here for any reason other than to ask for clarification on a particular aspect of the answer, and even then you should expect your comment to be deleted once the author has made a decision about addressing your point.  **Especially** please don't try to have tangential discussions in this comments thread.

Comment: https://opensource.org/definition-annotated#persons-or-groups

Answer (score 18):

**Yes you can** (but with big caveats)

There are several licences that disallow commercial use of the software (or other intellectual property). Most notably [CC BY-NC 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/) but please keep in mind that it's generally *not* recommended to use CC BY-NC 3.0 licence for software (you still can!).

There are several problems associated with this kind of licensing though mainly:

- What is a commercial use? Creative commons has this semi-covered by https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/NonCommercial_interpretation but your interpretation may differ from mine.
- It won't mix well with other software, specifically it'd be practically impossible to reuse that code outside of your project, or use it as a library.
- What about for-profit universities? what about not-for-profit ones? (different from non-profit). In my opinion any university that charges its student should be excluded, but practically everyone else differs from this opinion.
- What about foundations that also provide commercial services to fund their charitable work?

**Practical solution**

If you want to reduce commercial use one of the more effective ways is to choose very strict licence like AGPL 3.0 and dual licence it with a commercial licence.

While it does not strictly forbid the commercial use, it's strict virality and no "over the network" loopholes, make it toxic enough for most corporations to not touch it with a stick.

Even if some corporation does make use of it, they'll be required to share any improvements they make for it for free (with conditions).

**What exactly "Open Source" means differs depending on who you ask**

So take all answers with a grain of salt, some of the open source organizations recognize licences that restrict commercial use, most don't.

People often mix, misunderstand the meaning of the "free software" and "open source". It doesn't help the fact that often those terms are used incorrectly on purpose (eg. by commercial vendors that want "open source" badge just because they published a source code), or the fact that initially Free Software was synonymous with Open Source, but then meanings slightly diverged.

It also does not help when open source/free software community often cannot agree what is what.

Comment: This implies more difference between the Free Software Definition and Open Source Definition than there actually is.

Comment: There is not much difference Free Software is just more strict term then Open Source.

Comment: @a3nm I'd like to refer to other part of my answer: "It also does not help when open source/free software community often cannot agree what is what." Even the wikipedia page you've listed contains references to two other organizatiosn that disagree with their definition. OpenSource.org disagrees to as they list NPOSL-3.0 as an open licenceeven though it restricts comercial use.

Comment: [On this site](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) we use the FSF and OSI definitions of *free* and *open-source* respectively, so saying that you can have a free licence that disallows commercial activity is saying something factually inaccurate within the definitions of the site; -1 from me.  That said, I accept that OSI has approved NPOSL-3.0; if you cut all the material about other definitions of free and open source from your answer and left only the observations about NPOSL, I'd remove my downvote.  I'd probably upvote, because it's interesting and relevant.

Comment: NPOSL apparently does not restrict commercial use, but commercial licensing https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5776/why-is-the-non-profit-open-software-license-nposl-osi-approved. My issue was with the CC-NC licenses, which are not open-source even though an earlier version of the answer claimed they were.

Comment: "initially Free Software was synonymous with Open Source, but then meanings slightly diverged." This may be the story of hundreds of synonyms in the English language! :-)

Comment: CC BY-NC 3.0 does not prevent you from reusing the code or use it as a library, it explicitly allows you to do so. Only the used code itself must stay under CC license but without share-alike, the rest of the code can be any license. There is only a problem if the rest oft he code has a license that requires share-alike, as GPL does. GPL does not mix with CC but if your code uses BSD, MIT or Apache, that mixes fine with CC as long as the CC code continues to be redistributed under CC.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142442/discussion-on-answer-by-marcin-raczkowski-can-i-license-my-project-with-an-open).

Answer (score 11):

No, but you can get close enough: you can prevent your Open Source project from getting included in a closed-source project (for example, by using a [GPL](https://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/oem/) license), and then offer a dual-license option for companies who don't want to release their own proprietary code as open source.

[MySql](https://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/oem/) follows this model, and has since before Oracle bought them.

Comment: This is an excellent answer - if you're concerned about someone taking your open source work, incorporating it into their own proprietary work and not distributing their private changes back to you, the GPL provides a way to do that.

Answer (score 5):

## No.

#### Non commercial licenses are not open source. Additionally non commercial licenses are not free software, and do not meet the Debian Free Software Guidelines.

Open Source has a single definition - the [open source definition](https://opensource.org/osd), created by the group that created the term open source - [OSI](http://opensource.org/). **There is no other other group that purports to define the term open source.** However as there's been some confusion about related movements and their organisations particularly in one of the other answers, I will discuss these other movements and organisation in this answer.

#### Non commercial licenses are not open source as they conflict with part 6 of the [open source definition](https://opensource.org/osd)

> 6. No Discrimination Against Fields of Endeavor
>    The license must not restrict anyone from making use of the program in a specific field of endeavor. For example, it may not restrict the program from being used in a business, or from being used for genetic research.

#### Non commercial licenses are not free software, as they do not meet the  'Use' freedom of the free software definition

The [Free Software Foundation](https://www.fsf.org/) and the [GNU Project](https://www.gnu.org) [does not define open source](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.html), but rather a [separate concept](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.html) known as [Free Software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html).

> Thus, to exclude commercial use, commercial development or commercial distribution would hobble the free software community and obstruct its path to success. We must conclude that a program licensed with such restrictions does not qualify as free software.

#### Non commercial licenses do not meet the Debian Free Software Guidelines.

The Open Source Defintion was created from the [Debian Free Software Guidelines](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianFreeSoftwareGuidelines). The Debian Free Software Guidelines [do not attempt to define open source, but rather to define what software can be included in the Debian Linux distribution](https://www.debian.org/social_contract#guidelines).

> 6. No Discrimination Against Fields of Endeavor
>
> The license must not restrict anyone from making use of the program in a specific field of endeavor. For example, it may not restrict the program from being used in a business, or from being used for genetic research.

#### CC BY-NC 3.0 is not an open source license, software licensed by CC BY-NC 3.0 is not free software, software licensed by CC BY-NC 3.0 does not meet the Debian Free Software Guidelines.

I am mentioning this license  explicitly as one of the other answers incorrectly states that CC BY-NC 3.0 can be used for open source software. CC BY-NC 3.0 is a creative commons license, but CC BY-NC 3.0 is not an open source license, because CC BY-NC 3.0 does not meet the open source definition.