# Choose or write a proper license

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, license-recommendation, commercial, creative-commons

Is there a proper license (I have already checked MIT, LGPL, CC licenses),
which fits the following needs (conditions), or it has to be specify some way?

- BY (from CC): Attribution needed
- SA (from CC): Share-alike, the code can be continued, shared with the same conditions
- Share the source-code, e.g. on GitHub
- Commercial usage of the code is supervised, or granted by the code author. So if anybody would like to use the code for commercial, they have to contact the author.

Is this last one possible by any license?

I would not advise the coder to pick NC (from CC), which means 'no commercia'l usage, since it would kill any future commercial purposes, for him as well. The ND: no derivatives, can be also interesting option.

Comment: This license would not be open source; see [Can I license my project with an open-source license but disallow commercial use?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9805/can-i-license-my-project-with-an-open-source-license-but-disallow-commercial-use)

Comment: Note that the original author is allowed to grant extra licenses - even if you give everyone a CC BY-SA-ND, you can also give the company that paid $3000 an unlimited license - but authors of derivative versions can't. (Do you want them to be able to?)

Comment: Wow, your comment sounds extremely useful.