# Which license allows usage in end products (aimed at consumers) but not tools aimed at developers and companies?

Tags: licensing

I developed a project and I want to make the source code publicly available. I want everyone to be able to use the code as they see fit when used for developing end products (not sure if this is the right term, I mean software that is aimed at consumers), but I want to disallow people making tools aimed at developers and companies.

Is there a license that does this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I license my project with an open-source license but disallow commercial use?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9805/can-i-license-my-project-with-an-open-source-license-but-disallow-commercial-use) - while I know that's a slightly different use case, the answer is the same.

Comment: Yeah I settled on ZLib, I just want to be able to go to platform holders if someone offers a paid version hoping people dont know about the free one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there are no open-source licenses that meet your requirements.

An open-source license is not allowed to discriminate in what the software is used for. An open-source license can't forbid commercial usage and by the same token it can't forbid usage in a product aimed at non-consumers.

Comment: is there a non open source license perhaps?

Comment: @BasSmit, we can't advise you on non-open-source licenses. They are usually drafted on a case-by-case basis by lawyers.