# Are reimplementations of works with a non-commercial license usable commercially?

Tags: license, derivative-works, non-commercial

Nvidia releases some of its research works like Instant NGP with the source code. I was reading a paper and its license, ["Nvidia License"](https://github.com/NVlabs/CALM/blob/main/License.txt) and wondering if reimplementing the paper, for example in another reinforcement learning environment, would enable me to use it for a commercial work or relicense it and release the reimplmentation?

I will read the paper and also the source code. If I were to write the reimplementation from scratch, would that suffice as a non-derivative work? And what exactly does "separable" mean here?

> derivative works shall not include works that remain separable
> from, or merely link (or bind by name) to the interfaces of,
> the Work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [the Nvidia license is not an open source license due to it disallowing commercial use](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9805/can-i-license-my-project-with-an-open-source-license-but-disallow-commercial-use); questions about copyright without an open-source context can be asked on [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/).