# Github Public Repo License

Tags: licensing

I'm building a software which is publicly hosted on GitHub. Its deployed on Play Store as well.

I have a few contributory pull requests, but im concerned over possible legal complications over a long run.

I want to own the software by all means, this mean that contributions, once merged, are entity of the software owner (me).
I want to be able to sell or SaaS the software when I need to, without anyone else doing the same with my code.
This isn't supposed to be open source, since the word is misleading due to complete ownership, but anyone is free to contribute.

Any suggestion on existing, or modified LICENSE file may be suggested, Thanks!

Comment: I would vote to close as the OP does not want to use an open source license and the post is not appropriate to this site.

Comment: See also our canonical question [Can I license my project with an open-source license but disallow commercial use?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9805/can-i-license-my-project-with-an-open-source-license-but-disallow-commercial-use)