# Looking for the best licensing model

Tags: license-recommendation

I'm creating a large open source project that I hope will have many contributors. This project is expressly for collaboration and practice on using and creating industry best practices. While this project is an imaginary project, the code we create may serve many business cases. I want a license that will allow unfettered copying and view of the code but forbid using the code for private or corporate use without express permission. I want to protect the rights of all contributors and prevent exploitation of their hard work. What would be the best open source license for this task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I license my project with an open-source license but disallow commercial use?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9805/can-i-license-my-project-with-an-open-source-license-but-disallow-commercial-use)

Comment: As I understand the content of this link, "open" means open to everyone - whether for private or commercial purposes. But a *copy left* license will make it more difficult for commercial uses because the license also requires any derivatives to be copy left as well. I can still use a license that flat out forbids commercial use but then it won't be "open source" by definition. The provided link explains it much better.

Comment: You cannot prevent commercial use, but you can use a very strong copyleft license like AGPLv3 to prevent commercial users from taking your code and closing it. AGPLv3 also closes the loophole of network use.